# Reading XMl blob using and inserting specific values in a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008

There are around 100 such columns . One  column  in the blob currently looks like :

```
<GridDataVisibleColumn>
                <FilterBehavior>StronglyTyped</FilterBehavior>
                <FilterBarMode>Immediate</FilterBarMode>
                <AllowFilter>false</AllowFilter>
                <AllowSort>true</AllowSort>
                <AllowDrag>false</AllowDrag>
                <AllowGroup>true</AllowGroup>
                <AllowResize>true</AllowResize>
                <ShowColumnOptions>false</ShowColumnOptions>
                <HeaderText>XRef</HeaderText>
                <IncrementSeed>1</IncrementSeed>
                <IsIdentity>false</IsIdentity>
                <IsReadOnly>false</IsReadOnly>
                <MappingName>XRef</MappingName>
                <MinimumWidth>0</MinimumWidth>
                <Width>
                  <UnitType>None</UnitType>
                  <Value>150</Value>
                </Width>
                <DataType>String</DataType>
                <UpdateMode>LostFocus</UpdateMode>
                <IsHidden>false</IsHidden>
              </GridDataVisibleColumn>
```

SQL Query looks like  :

exec sp_xml_preparedocument @hdoc OUTPUT, @blobXML

```
insert into @tmpblob
(
RunDate,
Token,
OwnerId,
MappingName ,
HeaderText  ,
WidthUnitType,
WidthValue
)
select 
    @RunDate,
    @Token,
    @OwnerId,
    MappingName,
    HeaderText,
    WidthUnitType,
    WidthValue
from OPENXML(@hdoc, '/GridDataTableProperties/VisibleColumns/GridDataVisibleColumn/MappingName', 2)
with(
    MappingName                     VARCHAR (64) './text()'  ,
    HeaderText                      VARCHAR (64) './text()'  ,
    WidthUnitType               VARCHAR (64) './UnitType/text()' ,
    WidthValue                          VARCHAR (64) './Value/text()' 
    )

EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @hdoc
```

Just assume that everything is correct with the @tmpblob. I can post that as well but then it wont be consie. I want to know how can i display this xml in form of a table such as

MappingName HeaderText WidthUnitType WidthValue
XRef          XRef       None           150

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one -

```
DECLARE @XML XML
SELECT @XML = '
<GridDataVisibleColumn>
    <HeaderText>XRef</HeaderText>
    <MappingName>XRef</MappingName>
    <MinimumWidth>0</MinimumWidth>
    <Width>
        <UnitType>None</UnitType>
        <Value>150</Value>
    </Width>
    <DataType>String</DataType>
</GridDataVisibleColumn>'

SELECT 
      MappingName = t.c.value('MappingName[1]', 'VARCHAR(64)')
    , HeaderText = t.c.value('HeaderText[1]', 'VARCHAR(64)') 
    , WidthUnitType = t.c.value('Width[1]/UnitType[1]', 'VARCHAR(64)')
    , WidthValue = t.c.value('Width[1]/Value[1]', 'VARCHAR(64)') 
FROM @XML.nodes('/GridDataVisibleColumn') t(c)
```

Answer (score 2):

> I want to know how can i display this xml in form of a table such as

You just use the query you have that works for you?

Here is a modified version that works for the XML you have posted in your question.

```sql
exec sp_xml_preparedocument @hdoc OUTPUT, @blobXML

select 
  MappingName,
  HeaderText,
  WidthUnitType,
  WidthValue
from openxml(@hdoc, '/GridDataVisibleColumn', 2)
with(
    MappingName   VARCHAR (64),
    HeaderText    VARCHAR (64),
    WidthUnitType VARCHAR (64) 'Width/UnitType',
    WidthValue    VARCHAR (64) 'Width/Value' 
    )

exec sp_xml_removedocument @hdoc
```